# Does it take extra time to spawn a thread in a scoped Threadpool?

Tags: rust

Previously I was doing some simple concurrency based on rayon-rs [scope](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/fn.scope.html) function. I do this:

```rs
rayon::scope::(|s| {
    s.spawn(move |_| {
        // Do something  
    })
})
```

But this way calling `spawn` on `s`, some time is spent to initialize a new thread.

But if I build a threadpool like:

```rs
let pool = rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new().num_threads(8).build().unwrap();

pool.scope(|s| {
    s.spawn(move |_|{
        // Do something
    })
});
```

In this way after building the threadpool, I call `scope` function on the pool, then I call `spawn` on `s`. My assumption is, it should not take extra time to initialize a new thread by calling `spawn` function, because the threads are already built into the pool.

Is my assumption correct? If not, what can I do to achieve the same goal?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It shouldn't create new system threads indeed. Yet it still should take some non-zero time for rayon to determine which thread to run on, and to move the data in the thread scope, etc

Comment: no need, as would rather wait for a person with bigger expertise to find where we're both wrong :)

Comment: haha... ok! :).

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only difference between your two snippets is that the first one uses the global Rayon thread pool, and the second one uses your own thread pool, with fixed size. Unless you're caching the thread pool somewhere, your version will necessarily have to launch threads because the thread pool is freshly created. If you're caching it, then they should be equivalent (except for the number of threads). If you're not sure what you're supposed to do, I recommend just using the Rayon built-in thread pool.

Comment: @user4815162342 Hi, thank you for your detailed insight! So I have to cache the Threadpool in a struct or variable, and then reuse it, right? :).

Comment: @ino Yes - or just go with the default thread pool. In other words, what's the _reason_ you're building your own thread pool? This feels a bit like an xy problem.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks so much! Is the Global Threadpool already cached...or I have to cache it manually also? Sorry if my questions are dumb.

Comment: The global thread pool is already cached in a global variable (hence "global" thread pool), you don't need to do anything. The function `rayon::scope()` accesses it internally and uses that pool to schedule jobs.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for all your time and patience to answer my silly question, I appreciate it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But this way calling `spawn` on s, some time is spent to initialize a new thread.

`rayon::scope(|s| s.spawn(...))` doesn't create a new thread; it uses a global thread pool. This is [documented](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/fn.scope.html#a-note-on-threading).

> My assumption is, it should not take extra time to initialize a new thread by calling `spawn` function, because the threads are already built into the pool.

That is correct, but the same applies to `rayon::scope()`, the only difference being that it uses a global thread pool built into Rayon.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! this is the purpose of thread pool after all to use existing threads instead of creating new ones and destroying them each time.

From the doc of spawn [here](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.0/rayon/struct.ThreadPool.html#method.spawn):

> Spawns an asynchronous task in this thread-pool. This task will run in the implicit, global scope, which means that it may outlast the current stack frame -- therefore, it cannot capture any references onto the stack (you will likely need a move closure).

The difference between scope and spawn is that scope will wait for spawned tasks on returning while spawn will not. See more [here](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.0/rayon/fn.scope.html).
.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The OP is comparing `rayon::scope(|s| s.spawn(...))` with using a custom thread pool. Contrary to what this answer says, the former doesn't spawn threads unconditionally, it just uses a default global thread pool. This is spelled out in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/fn.scope.html#a-note-on-threading).

Comment: @user4815162342 Hey again! thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @ino The answer would be correct if the question had compared [`std::thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) (which does create a new thread every time) to the rayon thread pool. But you were asking about two different Rayon APIs, both of which pool their threads.

Comment: @user4815162342 Hi...would you mind writing a short answer so I could upvote and aceept it, so it could clarify the confusion and help future readers? :).